# Gremlin: The provided traverser does not map to a value

Tags: database, cassandra, gremlin, janusgraph, scylla

```
g.V()
    .has('atom', '_value', 'red').fold()
    .coalesce(unfold(), addV('atom').property('_value', 'red')).as('atom')
    .out('view').has('view', '_name', 'color').fold()
    .coalesce(unfold(), addE('view').from('atom').to(addV('view').property('_name', 'color')))
```

Gives me an error:

```
The provided traverser does not map to a value: []->[SelectOneStep(last,atom)] (597)
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it looks like when `as()` is followed by `fold()` it deletes the variable set in the `as()` step. I used `aggregate()` instead as follows:

```
g.V()
    .has('atom', '_value', 'red')
    .fold().coalesce(
        unfold(), 
        addV('atom').property('_value', 'red')
    )
    .aggregate('atom')
    .out('view').has('view', '_name', 'color')
    .fold().coalesce(
        unfold(), 
        addE('view')
            .from(select('atom').unfold())
            .to(addV('view').property('_name', 'color'))
            .inV()
    )
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding to this in case someone else comes across this.

This specific error occurs when you use the id as a string in `from()` instead of the vertex object.

To see what I mean, as a simple test run the following gremlin query:

`g.addE('view').from('atom').to(addV('view').property('_name', 'color'))`

then run this query:

`g.addE('view').from(V('atom')).to(addV('view').property('_name', 'color'))`

The first query will give you the error stated above, the second one will not.

Answer (score 2):

The `as()` step is what is known as a [reducing barrier step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#a-note-on-barrier-steps).  With reducing barrier steps any path history of a query (such as applying a label via `as()`) is lost. In reducing barrier steps many paths are reduced down to a single path.  After that step there would be no way to know which of the many original labeled vertices would be the correct one to retrieve.